# How to use findOrCreate in relationships - Adonis.js

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I have a user table, and a user address table.

so in the change of address route I would like to make some con

[Find Or Create](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_findorcreate_whereattributes_values)

I already have the relationship done `../Models/User.js`

```
address() {
  return this.hasOne('App/Models/UserAddress')
}
```

> Note: the relationship is working

```
await user.posts().fetch()
```

it works perfectly

but the code below doesn't work

```
const user = await User.findOrFail(auth.user.id)
const data = await request.only([
  'street',
  'number',
  'complement',
  'district',
  'city',
  'state',
  'zip'
])

user.address().findOrCreate(data)
```

but this generates an error

`user.address (...). findOrCreate is not a function`

could someone tell me the best way to do this `Find Or Create` in relationships?

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. `hasOne` returns `HasOne` object, which is a `BaseRelation` object, which does not have `findOrCreate`, which is only for Lucid Models.

I suggest, since you already have the user ID and I assume that is the foreign key referenced by your `Address` class to just do this

```
await Address.findOrCreate(
 { user: auth.user.id },
 {
   ... your data here,
 }
)
```